# Styling a bound string?

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-7, binding

How do I go about styling a bound string to a `TextBlock`? I'd like to have some of the text bolded, but not all of it?

```
<TextBlock Name="lblZoneNumber" Margin="12, 20, 0, 0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding ZoneSummary}" />
```

A sample of the text would be:

"Your vehicle, test1234, is currently parked in Grand Rapids, MI at zone 100" and I'd like to bold the text like: "Your vehicle, **test1234**, is currently parked in Grand Rapids, MI at **zone 100**."

I can't really make these textblocks programmatically as the text is part of a view model/pivotitem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do this until you start to develop for Mango, and then you would not use the `TextBlock` to do so, but the `RichTextBox`.  A `TextBlock` can only have one styling.  The `RichTextBox` is read only, BTW.

Here is a link to info about the `RichTextBox`: http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/Windows-Phone-7-Mango-First-look-at-RichTextBox-control

Comment: There is also a RichTextBox coming out from Component One, which I believe is also for Mango.  http://www.componentone.com/SuperProducts/StudioWindowsPhone/

Comment: I am using Mango... Perfect! Thanks!